# Is medsens() also appropriate for moderated mediation?

Tags: interaction, mediation, sensitivity-analysis

medsens() is a fantastic R-method for testing sensitivity of mediation models
estimated by mediate() method (mediation package by Tingley et al; Version
4.4.5). However, I'm wondering whether medsens() is also appropriate for moderated
mediation? And if not, is there an alternative procedure that allows to test
sensitivity of moderated mediation analysis?

More details: In one of my study, I find strong theoretical and empirical support for
moderated mediation (moderator is a dummy var; otherwise the model specs are
similar to the example in chapter 3.2
ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf).
However, my medsens() analysis finds only very poor Rho and R2 values.
Before throwing away the model, I wonder whether medsens is appropriate for
estimating sensitivity of moderated mediation models, entailing a
moderation*mediator interaction term.

And if medsens is not appropriate for moderated mediation: Would it be
enough enlightening to test sensitivity of two unmoderated mediation models
ran over two sub-datasets, split along the moderation dummy?